# Syntax in GAS UI service

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this line of code that has no effect on the listBox it creates... I'd like to adjust its height and font size, what am I missing ?

```
  var titre = app.createListBox(false).setId("titre").setName("titre").setHeight('45px').setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12").setStyleAttribute("verticalAlign","middle");
```

Thanks

Serge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not what you were looking for, but this very same code works for me. The only thing that didn't work, which is the only one you didn't complained :), was the verticalAlign thing.

Here is the full code of my test.

```js
function uiTest() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("UI");
  var titre = app.createListBox(false).setId("titre").setName("titre").setHeight('45px').
      setStyleAttribute("fontSize","16").setStyleAttribute("verticalAlign","middle");
  titre.addItem("test");
  var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel().add(
    titre).add(
    app.createLabel('example')).add(
    app.createListBox().addItem("test2"));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app.add(panel));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henrique, but when I test this I have 2 issues : .setHeight('45px') has no effect at all, I can remove it without any difference...  and also fontSize seems to be limited to about 14 Pt, or maybe 15 but never bigger :-//    cheers, Serge

Comment: Well Serge, maybe it's a browser issue. Have you tested it on another one? It works for both Firefox and Chromium on Linux for me.

Comment: You're right, it works on firefox but not on Google Chrome/mac & Safari... too bad because almost every users in my school are on these browsers :-/   thanks, Serge

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of all those: .setStyleAttribute()

```
  function applyCSS(element, style){
    for (var key in style){
      element.setStyleAttribute(key, style[key]); 
    }   
  }
```

I have a bunch of CSS here if that helps: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/gs-interactive